# It seems that Swift 4 does not support pattern matching tuple of enums

Tags: switch-statement, pattern-matching, tuples, swift4, state-machine

Is this a limitation in Swift 4 pattern matching or am I doing something wrong. I can't understand what the error message is referring to...

```
enum Event {
    case scan
    case stopScanning
}

enum State {
    case idle
    case scanning
}

let tuple: (State, Event) = (State.idle, Event.scan)

switch(tuple) {
case (.idle, .scan): return State.scanning
case (.scan, .stopScanning): return State.idle
default: return state
}
```

Produces error:

```
error: pattern cannot match values of type 'State'
        case (.scan, .stopScanning): State.idle
              ~^~~~
```

Answer (score 0):

(Immediately after writing the question I saw it... thanks SO for being my rubber duck.  I'm answering my own question in the hopes of saving somebody a little time if they get this error and don't immediately understand what it is saying and land here from google some day.)

The second case needs to have `.scanning` (`State`) *not* `.scan` (`Event`)

Following works:

```
        let t: (State, Event) = (state, event)
        switch(t) {
        case (.idle, .scan): return State.scanning
        case (.scanning, .stopScanning): return State.idle
        default: return state
        }
```

In retrospect, the Swift compiler was clearly telling me that the *second* case had incompatible enum value at 1st position in the tuple.